# Python check if two consecutives words in a list are words in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
a = ['The', 'man', 'is', 'eating', 'pear']
```

`eating` and `pear` are consecutive

```
b = ['these', 'are', 'random', 'words', 'but', 'they', 'have', 'pear', 'and', 'eating']
```

this is a random list of words I want to check if two CONSECUTIVE words in are words in b

How would I produce a list like

```
c = ['eating', 'pear']
```

Comment: For clarification, do the words need to be consecutive? E.g. if `'The'` were in list `b`, would you want it to show up in list `c` even though its  consecutive word `'man'` is not in list `b`?

Comment: Yes I only want the consecutive words in list c, even if only one of the words were in list b the consecutive word in list a needs to be in list b too

Answer (score 5):

```
c = [(x,y) for x, y in zip(a[0:], a[1:]) if x in b and y in b]
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

A loop will do

```
a = ['The', 'man', 'is', 'eating', 'pear', "these", "words", "mean", "nothing", "but", "words"]
b = ['these', 'are', 'random', 'words', 'but', 'they', 'have', 'pear', 'and', 'eating']

#make b a set to improve lookup times
set_b = set(b)
#list for the words found
consec = []
for i, item in enumerate(a[:-1]):
    #check consecutive words
    if item in set_b and a[i + 1] in set_b:
        #append pair if both words are in b
        consec.extend(a[i:i + 2])

#remove double entries by converting the list to a set        
print(set(consec)) 
#output is a set of words
#{'pear', 'words', 'eating', 'these', 'but'}
```

If the word order of `a` should be kept, you can do the following:

```
a = ['The', 'man', 'is', 'eating', 'pear', "these", "mean", "nothing", "but", "words"]
b = ['these', 'are', 'random', 'words', 'but', 'they', 'have', 'pear', 'and', 'eating']

set_b = set(b)
consec = []

for i, item in enumerate(a[:-1]):
    if item in set_b and a[i + 1] in set_b:
        #first word already in list?
        if item in consec:
            #include only second word
            consec.append(a[i + 1])
        else:
            #add the pair of words
            consec.extend(a[i:i + 2])

print(consec)
#output
#['eating', 'pear', 'these', 'but', 'words']
```